# Cannot get Immutable IDs

Tags: ios, swift, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get Immutable IDs for messages but I haven't able to get them. Here's what I tried to do:

1. endpoint : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/
2. Header: added Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId" (I had to use the escape
   "\" character to use the quotes)

I did my message list request before and after a change to the message's parent folder but the message "id" is not immutable.

Do we get any indication that the "Immutable" preference has been taken into account ?

Is it better that I switch to Outlook API (v1.0 or v2.0) to get the immutable IDs ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add header `Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId"` in both places, when you create a subscription and when you move the email.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we get any indication that the "Immutable" preference has been
>   taken into account ?

Just waiting for the official states, any indication is not necessarily reliable.

> Is it better that I switch to Outlook API (v1.0 or v2.0) to get the
>   immutable IDs ?

Yes for real production applications, beta version is mainly for test/preview.

> Important: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in
>   preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production
>   applications is not supported.